# discord.py embed object function add_field parameter inline=True doesn't work for mobile?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am looking at the API here https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed under the Embed object function `add_field(*, name, value, inline=True)` and the `inline=True` shows up good on web. When I look on the mobile app though the output appears as it would on web if the inline parameter was set to False.

Does anyone know if this is a bug currently and if there's any anticipated fix?

Answer (score 0):

This is a 'bug' in the mobile app, it may be intentional due to how mobile screens work (being portrait and all) so it's nothing to do with you, it would be discords fault (or not) there.

Comment: Do you know where I should submit a feature request for this? I'm not sure if it would be Discord since I'm using a third-party python API.

Comment: It would be to discord, since its not the API or you thats at fault, its their mobile app.